# What is the right way to find the type of variables of `struct` type in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, swift5

As of now, I am using `type(of: )` function to find out the dynamic type of a variable and I compare it with `Type.self` to check the type :

```swift
var x = 5
if(type(of: x) == Int.self)
{
    print("\(x) is of type Int")
}
```

Am I doing it right ? Or is there any better/preferred way to check the type ?

Comment: Your approach is totally fine.

Comment: This kind of type check at runtime is *unswifty*. Better check types at **compile** time with generics, protocols, conditional conformance or method overloads.

Comment: @vadian I am not going to use this in my program. I am a Java developer who is learning Swift right now. So, I want to know the various approaches for achieving things in Swift. Thanks for your response :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i personaly would use

```
if(x is Int)
{
    print("\(x) is of type Int")
}
```

rather than using typeof if you're expecting x to be an integer as it's far more readable. but sure, you can use typeOf if you want to. Both are equally right

Answer (score 1):

You can use;

```
if (x is Int) {
    print("\(x) is of type Int")
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the difference between using `is` operator and using the `Type.self` which I used above ? Which one is the better approach and why ?